# How to convert NSstring to Nsdate

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am getting response from service that

```
"created_at" = "Thu Jul 06 07:26:23 +0000 2017";
```

i want to convert the string  into Nsdate  format 
i do not know how to do it

Comment: "format i do not know how to do it": By reading the doc and what each part of the format means http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: Take your pick: [How to convert NSString to NSDate](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=How+to+convert+NSstring+to+Nsdate).

Comment: Use http://www.sdfonlinetester.info/ to know and check all the format

Comment: Useful for this http://nsdateformatter.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSString *dateString = @"Thu Jul 06 07:26:23 +0000 2017";

NSDate *date =[[NSDate alloc] init];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss Z yyyy";
date = [ dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

Comment: @Shakti pleasure, can you please accept answer and upvote

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

> (source::http://nsdateformatter.com)

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss Z yyyy"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Thu Jul 06 07:26:23 +0000 2017"]];
    NSLog(@"date is %@ ",date);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDateFormatter *f = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[f setDateFormat:@"E MMM d HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"];
NSDate *date = [f dateFromString:@"Thu Jul 06 07:26:23 +0000 2017"];
```

Comment: Date Format would not work... should be: [f setDateFormat:@"E MMM d HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"];... There is no comma after the day

Comment: @Burnie777 Its work for me with or without comma also. I check both results.

Comment: Anyway, its helpfull to questioner to solve his issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
NSString *dateString = @"2018-07-27 03:08:10";

NSDate *date =[[NSDate alloc] init];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:";
date = [ dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

Answer (score -1):

**ObjectiveC** implemetation

```
NSString *dateString = @"Thu Jul 06 07:26:23 +0000 2017";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSDate *date =[[NSDate alloc] init];

dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"EEE MMM DD hh:mm:ss Z yyyy";

date = [dateFormatter dateFromString: dateString]; //generates date from dateString
```

---

**Swift** implementation goes below

```
let dateString = "Thu Jul 06 07:26:23 +0000 2017"

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE MMM DD hh:mm:ss Z yyyy"
dateFormatter.date(from: dateString) //"Jan 6, 2017, 12:56 PM"
```